# sum of numbers not having desired effect jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm relatively new to `javascript`/`jQuery` and I'm having trouble getting my expected outcome. I would like the total to be shown even if only one input has a value, otherwise I want 0 to be shown. However right now it requires all 3 values to be input before it will show the sum. It will not simply add the next input onto the total as I type into an input. I can imagine a series of lengthy conditional statements that would cross check each input for .length and return the total based on each input. Surely there has to be an easier/cleaner way. If this were java I would use total += (variable) and it would total them as I went. That doesn't seem to work here.

```
    $('#invoice_labor, #invoice_materials, #invoice_other').keyup(function() {  
        if ($('#invoice_labor').length || $('#invoice_materials').length || $('#invoice_other').length ) {
            updateTotal();        
        } else {
            $('#invoice_total').html(0);
        }
    });     
    var updateTotal = function () {
        var input1 = parseFloat($('#invoice_labor').val(), 2);
        var input2 = parseFloat($('#invoice_materials').val(), 2);
        var input3 = parseFloat($('#invoice_other').val(), 2);
        var total = input1 + input2 + input3;      
        $('#invoice_total').html(total);
        $("#invoice_total").html(parseFloat($("#invoice_total").html()).toFixed(2));         
    };
```

and here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HQaXz/) I was tinkering with.

So I want the total to change regardless of which field I type a number into. If it's only one, total that add that to the total variable and return it. If it's any combination of two then combine them and add them to the total. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `parseFloat` doesn't take 2 parameters

Comment: @Ian thank you, so the , 2 is useless?

Comment: Yeah, effectively. It seems that it's ignored. Although I wouldn't be surprised if there's inconsistencies between browsers, so I'd remove it anyways.

Comment: Also, note that input like `23.23faf` will be parsed as `23.23`. That's the nature of `parseFloat` (and `parseInt`), so you might want to use `Number("user input")` to *convert* to a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('#invoice_labor, #invoice_materials, #invoice_other').keyup(function() {  
    updateTotal();        
});     
var updateTotal = function () {
    var input1 = parseFloat($('#invoice_labor').val()) || 0;
    var input2 = parseFloat($('#invoice_materials').val()) || 0;
    var input3 = parseFloat($('#invoice_other').val()) || 0;
    var total =  input1 + input2 + input3;      
    $("#invoice_total").html(total.toFixed(2));         
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zzxwV/)

Your fiddle has few problesm

1. You were registering the input keyup event, in the body keyup handler which was wrong - it will cause the first keystroke not to be recognised and will fire multiple updatetotal calls in subsequent calls
2. If a field is empty parseFloat will return NaN which when added will result in NaN as the result
3. parseFloat takes only one argument